# How to compare two lists in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I have two breeds, buyers and suppliers, and buyers are building a list (sup_list) of suppliers that have attributes stored in list 'att' that are greater than a list of criteria stored in list 'b'. The following line does this for the first criteria - is there an easy way to add in all the others?

```
ask buyers [set sup_list suppliers with [item 0 att > [item 0 b] of myself]]
```

So in English the criteria would be: item 0 > item 0 AND item 1 > item 1 AND item 2 > item 3 etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The expression you want is:

```
suppliers with [ reduce and (map > att [ b ] of myself) ]
```

This is a tricky bit of functional programming. Let's see how it works.

Our first goal is to take the two lists of numbers and turn it into a single list of boolean values, where each item will be `true` if the item at the same location in the buyer's list is greater than the item at the same location in the supplier's list. For example, if we have:

- Buyer's list: `[1 1 1 1]`
- Supplier's list: `[2 1 1 1]`

...only the first item in the supplier's list fits our criteria, so we want our resulting list to be:

- `[true false false false]`

Whenever we want to turn one or more lists of things into a single list of things, the NetLogo primitive to use is [`map`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map). The [`map`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map) primitive takes a reporter and one or more lists. It applies the reporter to item(s) taken from the list(s) and builds a new list out of that. This is exactly what we need. Try this in the NetLogo command center:

```
observer> show (map > [2 1 1 1] [1 1 1 1])
observer: [true false false false]
```

A couple of things to note:

- Since we are passing more than one list to [`map`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map), we need to put the whole expression inside parentheses.
- We are using concise syntax for passing `>` as a reporter. This could also have been written `[ [a b] -> a > b ]`.

Now that we have our list of boolean values, we want to check if *all* these values are `true`, i.e., if all supplier items fit the buyer's criteria. NetLogo has an [`all?`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#all) primitive that does something like that for agentsets, but we cannot use it here since we are dealing with a list. We will have to use [`reduce`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#reduce) instead.

The [`reduce`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#reduce) primitive is the one to use whenever we want to turn a list into a single value. Here, we want to turn a list of booleans into a single boolean value, that will be `true` if all the values in the list are `true` and will be `false` otherwise.

As the NetLogo documentation says, "it can be difficult to develop an intuition about what `reduce` does". (I strongly urge you to read the documentation and try experimenting with the primitive.) In a nutshell, it traverses a list and applies a reporter to each item and an "accumulator" value, storing the result of that operation in the accumulator. The first item of the list is used to initialize the accumulator.

In our case, the reporter used with `reduce` will be `and`, since we want to check that the first item is `true`, *and* that the second item is `true`, *and* that the third item is `true`, etc.

Let's try to reduce our previously obtained list of booleans:

```
observer> show reduce and [true false false false]
observer: false
```

(Not that we're, again, using the concise syntax to pass `and` as a reporter. This could have been written `[ [p q] -> p and q ]`.)

The end result is `false`, because not all values are true. Let's see how this works, step by step:

- it stores the first item from the list in the accumulator, so the accumulator now holds the value `true`.
- it passes the value of the accumulator and the value of the second item to the `and` reporter. The accumulator is `true` but the second item is `false`. The result of `true and false` is `false`, so it stores `false` in the accumulator.
- it passes the value of the accumulator and the value of the third item to the `and` reporter. The accumulator is now `false` and the second item is also `false`. The result of `false and false` is `false`, so again, it stores `false` in the accumulator.
- the fourth step is just like the third: the accumulator holds `false` and the fourth item is also `false`. The result of `false and false` is `false`, so again, it stores `false` in the accumulator.

Once we run out of list items, `reduce` reports the value of the accumulator, in this case `false`. The only case where it would report `true` is if all values in the list are `true`, leading to a sequence of `true and true` comparisons that all result in storing `true` in the accumulator. That's exactly what we want:

```
observer> show reduce and [true true true true]
observer: true
```

If you put all of this together, you should be able to see how:

```
suppliers with [ reduce and (map > att [ b ] of myself) ]
```

...gives you the agentset of suppliers that fit all criteria of the buyer!

(Note that `with` returns an agentset, not a list, so you should probably rename your `sup_list` variable...)

Comment: Thank you (I know you tried to explain map to me once before...)